# In Articulate would using Girl Band as the description for Girls Aloud violate the rules

Tags: taboo

Could the good people of Stack Exchange settle an argument - "not so recent girl band" was used as a description for Girls Aloud. Does the fact girl is a word in both the clue and the question violate the rules, or is the fact it's clearly meant more generally in the clue (e.g. it could have just as easily been Sugababes) mean it's ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you may not give that clue. It's the word, not the exact meaning, that is disallowed. The example given in the Taboo rules is that if "baseball" is part of the answer then you may not use "base" or "ball" - and both of those words have much broader meanings than just their baseball meanings.

Comment: The Taboo tag means the question is about that game; no need to hedge your answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've accepted that - and you're right the question was about Articulate but I didn't have enough privileges to create a tag and Taboo was the closest I could think of that existed.